# SSRS Map layer visibility for multi valued parameter issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to show visibility of the map layer in SSRS based on multi valued Parameter. 
below expression is giving me errors because of multi valued parameter

```
=iif(Parameters!DataLayer.Value ="LeadStatus", "Visible", "Hidden")
```

i have the following parameters "LeadStatus" and "Industry".

Can you help me how i can write the above expression for multi valued parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this : -

```
=iif(Parameters!DataLayer.Value ="LeadStatus", False, True)
```

In the visibility settings you use boolean values for hidden attribute. `True` when you want it hidden, `False` when you want it visible.